# How can I "shift" certain column values to different rows in an existing table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm implementing a queue as a ring buffer in a table along the lines of what Thomas Kejser talks about here: [Implementing Message Queues in Relational Databases](http://blog.kejser.org/2012/05/25/implementing-message-queues-in-relational-databases) If the ring buffer fills up, I have to increase the number of slots and possibly shift some of the values around. This is part of my routine to add slots to the ring buffer

I have a table that looks like this:

```
SlotId    SlotVal1  SlotVal2
1          3           3
2          4           4
3          1           1
4          2           2
5          NULL        NULL
6          NULL        NULL
7          NULL        NULL
8          NULL        NULL
```

I would like to "shift" the values from slots 3 and 4 forward by 4 slots to rows 7 and 8 so the table would look like this:

```
SlotId  SlotVal1 SlotVal2
1       3        3
2       4        4
3       NULL     NULL
4       NULL     NULL
5       NULL     NULL
6       NULL     NULL
7       1        1
8       2        2
```

I tried two different UPDATE queries to shift the rows forward and then clear the previous rows.  The first query (as reproduced below) doesn't update any rows in my table and I'm drawing a blank on what I must have left out:

```
        -- shift slot values forward
        DECLARE @firtRowToMove AS int = 3;  -- slot id of the first row to move
        DECLARE @rowsToShift AS int = 4; -- number of rows forward to shift
        UPDATE [SlotTable] 
        SET [SlotVal1] = (SELECT [SlotVal1]
                          FROM [SlotTable] AS s2
                          WHERE s2.[SlotId] = ([SlotId] - @rowsToShift)),
            [SlotVal2] = (SELECT [SlotVal2]
                          FROM [SlotTable] AS s2
                          WHERE s2.[SlotId] = ([SlotId] - @rowsToShift))
        WHERE [SlotId] >= (@firtRowToMove + @rowsToShift);
```

Comment: Are you trying to make this a generic "thing" or is this a one time type of activity? If it's generic, could you help my poor brain understand the logic for how one would determine how far forward a thing advances?

Comment: Are these `INT` columns? Can you describe the difference between `--` and `NULL`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, those are int columns and I used the "--" only to indicate where the values came from.  They would be updated to NULL as part of the same transaction.

Comment: @billinkc I don't think the logic for determining the number of rows to shift matters, but if you want to know the larger context, I'm implementing a queue as a ring buffer in a table along the lines of what Thomas Kejser talks about here: http://blog.kejser.org/2012/05/25/implementing-message-queues-in-relational-databases.  If the ring buffer fills up, I have to increase the number of slots and possibly shift some of the values around.  This is part of my routine to add slots to the ring buffer.

Comment: Will the destination rows always exist or does a solution need to determine insert/update logic as well?

Comment: @billinkc The destination rows will always exist and be empty (or populated only with the SlotId).

Comment: Btw, it seems the problem is with the sub-query for the SET clause.  If I replace the SELECT with a hard-coded integer, the rows are updated exactly as I would expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to qualify `SlotId` in your sub-query with `SlotTable` or it will use the `SlotId` from the sub-query itself.

```
UPDATE [SlotTable] 
SET [SlotVal1] = (SELECT [SlotVal1]
                  FROM [SlotTable] AS s2
                  WHERE s2.[SlotId] = ([SlotTable].[SlotId] - @rowsToShift)),
    [SlotVal2] = (SELECT [SlotVal2]
                  FROM [SlotTable] AS s2
                  WHERE s2.[SlotId] = ([SlotTable].[SlotId] - @rowsToShift))
WHERE [SlotId] >= (@firtRowToMove + @rowsToShift);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6637/2)

BTW, your [CTE version does not work either](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6637/3)

Another way to do what you do in this update statement a bit more efficiently (at least in my tests).

```
update s1
set SlotVal1 = s2.SlotVal1,
    SlotVal2  = s2.SlotVal2
from SlotTable as s1
  inner join SlotTable as s2
    on s2.SlotId = s1.SlotId - @rowsToShift
where s1.SlotId >= @firtRowToMove + @rowsToShift
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now.  As an aside, my actual CTE query was working, but it was because I had aliased the SlotId column in the subquery so it was no longer ambiguous.  I just failed to include that detail in the simplified version of the query that I posted here.  And thanks for the more efficient version of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I got a version of the query with a CTE to work for me, but as Mikael Eriksson points out in his answer, it had nothing to do with using a CTE and everything to do with fully qualifying the ambiguous reference to the SlotId column in the sub-select.